# Обособление оборота "с целью облагородить..."

Tags: пунктуация

Сегодня студенты вышли на субботник, с целью облагородить территорию между вторым и первым корпусом.

Comment: Почему номера корпусов даны в убывающем порядке? Это важно? Нейтрально звучит "между первым и вторым".

Answer (score 3):

Сегодня студенты вышли на субботник с целью облагородить территорию между вторым и первым корпусом.

Не нужна запятая, это структура простого предложения, **обстоятельственный оборот входит в основное сообщение.**

**Сравнить:** Сегодня на субботник, **с целью облагородить территорию между вторым и первым корпусом,** вышли студенты всех курсов.

Здесь обстоятельственный оборот является аналогом придаточного предложения цели и обособляется.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!